# Expanding taylor series using relation between successive terms with a specified tolerance in spyder

Tags: python, taylor-series

I have used this code to determine the value of e^pi with a specified tolerance in spyder(Python 3.8).

```
from math import*
term=1
sum=0
n=1
while (abs(e**pi-term))>0.0001:
    term=term*pi/n
    sum+=term
    n+=1
print(sum,e**pi)
```

I ran this code several times. But spyder is not showing anything when I run this code. I am new to python. So now I have no way to know whether this code is correct or not. It would be beneficial if you could verify whether this code is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the taylor series for e^x is sum n=0 to inf of x^n / n! which you seem to be doing correctly by multiplying by pi/n during each iteration.

One problem I noticed was with your while loop condition. To check the error of the function, you should be subtracting your current `sum` from the actual value. This is why you enter the infinite loop, because your `term` will approach 0, so the difference will approach the actual value, e^pi, which is always greater than .0001 or whatever your error is.

Additionally, since we start n at 1, we should also start sum at 1 because the 0th term of the taylor series is already 1. This is why you enter the infinite loop, because

Therefore, our code should look like this:

```
from math import*
term = 1
sum = 1
n = 1
while (abs(e ** pi - sum)) > 0.0001:
    term = term * pi / n
    sum += term
    n += 1
print(sum,e**pi)
```

Output:

```
23.140665453179782 23.140692632779263
```

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

The while loop does not end.

I have stuck in a condition to break out of the loop (at 10,000 cycles) to show this:

```
from math import*
term=1
sum=0
n=1

while (abs(e**pi-term))>0.0001:
    term=term*pi/n
    sum+=term
    n+=1
    if n > 10_000:
        print('large n')
        break
print(sum,e**pi)
```

If you replace the while loop with a for loop, then you can see each iteration as follows.

```
term=1
sum=0

for n in range(1, 101):
    term=term*(math.pi)/n
    sum+=term
    print(n, sum, math.e**math.pi)
```

And this is the result for the first 10 items:

```
1 3.141592653589793 23.140692632779263
2 8.076394854134472 23.140692632779263
3 13.244107634184441 23.140692632779263
4 17.30281976060121 23.140692632779263
5 19.852983800478555 23.140692632779263
6 21.188246569333145 23.140692632779263
7 21.787511098653937 23.140692632779263
8 22.02284172901283 23.140692632779263
9 22.104987615623955 23.140692632779263
10 22.13079450701397 23.140692632779263
```

The numbers are getting larger, hence the `while` loop was never exited (and your laptop probably got quite hot in the process !!).